# How to justify each step in proving that W is a subspace of V

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given that the $V$ is the set of all real $2\times2$ matrices, how would one justify that $W$ is a subset of $V$, if

$$W = \left\{ {\begin{pmatrix}
    a & b\\
    -b & a
  \end{pmatrix}\bigg|\ a,b\in\mathbb{R}}\right\}$$

My approach uses 3 criteria i), ii) and iii):

**i) $0\in W$**

I let $a,b=0$, to show that $0 = {\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0\\
    0 & 0  \end{pmatrix}\in W}$

**ii) If $v\in W$ and $w\in W$, then $v+w \in W$**

I let $v = {\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2\\
    -2 & 1  \end{pmatrix}\in W}$ and $v = {\begin{pmatrix}
    3 & 4\\
    -4 & 3  \end{pmatrix}\in W}$ to show that $v+w = \begin{pmatrix}
    4 & 6\\
    -6 & 4  \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}$

**iii) If $v\in W$ and $k\in \mathbb{R}$, then $kv\in W$, where $k$ is a scalar constant**

I let $v = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2\\
    -2 & 1  \end{pmatrix}$ and $k = 2$, so, $ kv = 2\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2\\
    -2 & 1  \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 4\\
    -4 & 2  \end{pmatrix}\in W$

I would like to know if I've correctly justified that each of the 3 criteria are valid, and that $W$ is indeed a subspace of $V$? If not, what is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: This idea is correct (but note you accidentally use 'subset' instead of 'subspace' in your question (which of course would also be true :) )

If you want to be more precise, put two generic elements explicitly (so take A and B in W) and show that for ii) and iii) that we have A+B is in W, and kA in W) too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is correct but to be more general and rigorous we should use generic elements for W, as for example for property ii)

$$v_1 = {\begin{pmatrix}
    a_1 & b_1\\
    -b_1 & a_1  \end{pmatrix}\in W}\quad v_2 = {\begin{pmatrix}
    a_2 & b_2\\
    -b_2 & a_2  \end{pmatrix}\in W}\\\implies v_1 +v_2= {\begin{pmatrix}
    a_1+a_2 & b_1+b_2\\
    -b_1-b_2 & a_1+a_2  \end{pmatrix}\in W}$$

and similarly for property iii).